# Alert message when starting shiny

Tags: r, shiny

The executable code below shows an alert when the Exclude farms option is selected. This same alert shows which industries will be excluded. However, I would like to generate a new feature that is if there is no industry to exclude, that is, if the "ind_exclude" of the code is empty. I would like a message alert to appear as soon as shiny starts, saying: "No there are industries to be excluded"

```
library(shiny)
library(rdist)
library(geosphere)
library(tidyverse)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinythemes)

function.cl<-function(df){

  #database df
  df<-structure(list(Industries = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7), 
                     Latitude = c(-23.8, -23.8, -23.9, -23.9, -23.9,-23.8,-23.8), 
                     Longitude = c(-49.8, -49.8, -49.5, -49.8, -49.8,-49.5,-49.8), 
                     Waste = c(526, 350, 526, 469, 285, 433, 456)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))


  coordinates<-subset(df,select=c("Latitude","Longitude")) 
  d<-distm(coordinates[,2:1]) 
  diag(d)<-1000000 
  min_distancia<-as.matrix(apply(d,MARGIN=2,FUN=min))
  limite<-mean(min_distancia)+sd(min_distancia) 

  search_vec <- function(mat, vec, dim = 1, tol = 1e-7, fun = all)
    which(apply(mat, dim, function(x) fun((x - vec) > tol)))
  ind_exclude<-search_vec(min_distancia,limite,fun=any)
  if(is_empty(ind_exclude)==FALSE){
    for (i in 1:dim(as.array(ind_exclude))){
      df<-subset(df,Industries!=ind_exclude[i])}}


  return(list(
    "IND" =  ind_exclude
  ))

}

ui <- bootstrapPage(
  navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"), collapsible = TRUE,
             "Cl", 
             tabPanel("Solution",
                      sidebarLayout(
                        sidebarPanel(

                          selectInput("filter1", h3("Select farms"),
                                      choices = list("All farms" = 1, 
                                                     "Exclude farms" = 2),
                                      selected = 1),


                        ),
                        mainPanel(
                          tabsetPanel())))))  

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  Modelcl<-reactive({
    function.cl(df)
  })

  output$ind <- renderTable({
    IND <- ((Modelcl()[[1]]))
  })
  observe({
    if(input$filter1 == 2){
      sendSweetAlert(
        session = session,
        title = "Information!",
        btn_labels = c("Yes", "No"),
        text = tags$div(h5("The industries that need to exclude are:"), 
                        paste(Modelcl()[[1]], collapse = ", ")
        ),

        type = "info"
      )
    }
  })


}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: What is the object that you need to check the lenght?

Comment: The code "ind_exclude" shows that the industries that need to be excluded are 3 and 6. However, I would like to make an alert that if there was no industry to be excluded, it shows an alert as soon as shiny starts, saying: No there are industries to be excluded.

Comment: can't you just add another observe sendSweerAlert for that?

Comment: I think so. But how would the "if" look like for this new alert?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Bruno mentioned, add an observer to the object you want to look for that might be empty. You just need to test if the object is NULL/empty/has no values. Here is an app that uses `rlang::is_empty` to check if a data.frame is empty. If it is an alert is sent including at the start of the app (I created a new reactive object `Modelcl2` that is always empty just to demonstrate the approach of observing with an if statement):

```
library(shiny)
library(rdist)
library(geosphere)
library(tidyverse)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinythemes)

function.cl<-function(df){

  #database df
  df<-structure(list(Industries = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7), 
                     Latitude = c(-23.8, -23.8, -23.9, -23.9, -23.9,-23.8,-23.8), 
                     Longitude = c(-49.8, -49.8, -49.5, -49.8, -49.8,-49.5,-49.8), 
                     Waste = c(526, 350, 526, 469, 285, 433, 456)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))


  coordinates<-subset(df,select=c("Latitude","Longitude")) 
  d<-distm(coordinates[,2:1]) 
  diag(d)<-1000000 
  min_distancia<-as.matrix(apply(d,MARGIN=2,FUN=min))
  limite<-mean(min_distancia)+sd(min_distancia) 

  search_vec <- function(mat, vec, dim = 1, tol = 1e-7, fun = all)
    which(apply(mat, dim, function(x) fun((x - vec) > tol)))
  ind_exclude<-search_vec(min_distancia,limite,fun=any)
  if(is_empty(ind_exclude)==FALSE){
    for (i in 1:dim(as.array(ind_exclude))){
      df<-subset(df,Industries!=ind_exclude[i])}}


  return(list(
    "IND" =  ind_exclude
  ))

}

ui <- bootstrapPage(
  navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"), collapsible = TRUE,
             "Cl", 
             tabPanel("Solution",
                      sidebarLayout(
                        sidebarPanel(

                          selectInput("filter1", h3("Select farms"),
                                      choices = list("All farms" = 1, 
                                                     "Exclude farms" = 2),
                                      selected = 1),


                        ),
                        mainPanel(
                          tabsetPanel())))))  

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  Modelcl<-reactive({
    function.cl(df)
  })

  Modelcl2<-reactive({
    data.frame()
  })

  output$ind <- renderTable({
    IND <- ((Modelcl()[[1]]))
  })
  observe({
    if(input$filter1 == 2){
      sendSweetAlert(
        session = session,
        title = "Information!",
        btn_labels = c("Yes", "No"),
        text = tags$div(h5("The industries that need to exclude are:"), 
                        paste(Modelcl()[[1]], collapse = ", ")
        ),

        type = "info"
      )
    }
  })

  observe({
    if(is_empty(Modelcl2())){
      sendSweetAlert(session = session,
                     title = "Hey",
                     btn_labels = c("Yes", "No"),
                     text = "nothing to exclude",

                     type = "info"
      )
    }
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Here is a very minimal example to show to bare bones workflow. You could also do a test if it is a dataframe based on the number of rows `if(nrow(dataframe) < 1)` or something like that, just find a test that works for the type of object you are working with:

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(shinyWidgets)


ui <- bootstrapPage()

server <- function(input, output, session) {


  Modelcl2 <-reactive({
    data.frame()
  })

  observe({
    if(rlang::is_empty(Modelcl2())){
      sendSweetAlert(session = session,
                     title = "Hey",
                     btn_labels = c("Yes", "No"),
                     text = "nothing to exclude",

                     type = "info"
      )
    }
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I did it in my case and it worked. Now just a doubt, in case you can answer. Rather than being an empty list, I would like to show a message at the beginning only when there are industries to exclude, what would my "observe" look like?

Comment: I can ask a new question, no problem. Would you know how to help me?

Comment: So just testing for the opposite?  To test that that dataframe is not empty try !is_empty, is_empty == FALSE, or nrow > 0.

Comment: Please bs93, could you take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62008422/new-functionality-for-confirmsweetalert-button-in-shiny